# Pass variable value to column name sqlite3 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to alter a table by adding a column, but instead of naming it directly in the sql statement I want to use a variable value instead, so I can keep on adding columns with a loop further on. Further variables have several types, from integers, floats, strings and even dates.

```
import sqlite3
db_path = "/Users/mbp2013/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Code/xml_echo_script/echo_db.db"

conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
db = conn.cursor()

variable = "whatever"
db.execute("ALTER TABLE echo ADD COLUMN ?", (variable))
```

However, I keep getting a sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

I'm using sqlite 3 and python 3.8.3.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You probably wanted to use a Python based string replacement:

```
import sqlite3

db_path = "/Users/mbp2013/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Code/xml_echo_script/echo_db.db"
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
db = conn.cursor()
variable = "whatever"
db.execute(f"ALTER TABLE echo ADD COLUMN {variable}")
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But what if the variable type is not a string, but rather an integer, a float of even a date?

Comment: That also works. It will convert to text. See https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals for details.

Comment: That won't necessarily work because they wouldn't be valid column names. What you attempted to do was the correct logic, it just won't work for column names or table names. _Do not_ resort to f-strings for inserting data in queries - parameterization was the right approach for that

Comment: Indeed when I tried it with string variable it worked, but not with other undeclared variable types. Plus when I try to run a loop for adding new columns named after a list, where the first value is 2D/Ao, it gives me a new error: sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "2D"

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import sqlite3

db_path = '/Users/mbp2013/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Code/xml_echo_script/echo_db.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
db = conn.cursor()

variable = 'whatever varchar'
db.execute('''ALTER TABLE echo ADD COLUMN ''' + variable)
```

Column name must follow the following guidelines:

1. Must not be a keyword (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)
2. Must start with alpha character or underline, and followed only by alphanumeric characters or underline.

Comment: Thanks. That works for strings, but for some reason it always fails if numbers are a part of the variable, even if I declare it as a string, either with commas or variable = str(variable)

Comment: Give me sample of your variable here.

Comment: For example 2D or 2D/Ao.

Comment: Can’t start with a digit. Can’t contain slash.